# First child with intermediate wrapping dics

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div some_unique_identifier class="whatever">
    <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div some_unique_identifier2 class="whatever2">
    <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to stylize only the first div with class `content`, but I cannot use `.wrapper .content:first-child` because of the `whatever` divs in the middle. How'd I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply like

```
.wrapper > div > .content:first-child{

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need only to style first occurrence of content class. As far as i know you can't do it with css. because in CSS pseudo will get immediate parents first child (if you are using :first-child).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div some_unique_identifier class="whatever">
    <div class="content">1</div>
  </div>
  <div some_unique_identifier2 class="whatever2">
    <div class="content">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use JQuery or Javascript like this:

```
$('.content').first().addClass('first-content');
```

and css:

```
.first-content{
  background:red;
}
```

Check **[This](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/ya0wn4es/1/)**

Comment: This will work for a one time things but adding too many JQuery selectors like this will really slow down the page.  If there ends up being hundreds of .contents on the page ... or ".wrapper .content"'s on the page that query will get heavy.  In addition to the query, you'll have to add an additional class to each found element.  Correct style selectors get optimized by the renderer rather than javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, use the first whatever or first div..

```
.wrapper > div:first-child .content
```

I explicitly use the direct-child selector (`>`), otherwise each and every div inside `.wrapper` which is the first child of it's parent (so also `.whatever` and `.whatever2`) would be selected

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways depending on your code structure. Now I am assuming that the same structure you are following. 
First way :

```css
.content:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div some_unique_identifier class="whatever">
    <div class="content">
      Content 1
  </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content 1 2nd child
  </div>
  <div some_unique_identifier2 class="whatever2">
    <div class="content">
      Content 2
  </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content 2 2nd child
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper div > div.content:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
//Another way:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div some_unique_identifier class="whatever">
    <div class="content">
      Content 1
  </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content 1 2nd child
  </div>
  <div some_unique_identifier2 class="whatever2">
    <div class="content">
      Content 2
  </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content 2 2nd child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is so close.  If you don't want to have to specify the div in between you don't need to.

```
.wrapper :first-child > .content
```

Example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8OXII65hZpiCGTFh2Py?p=preview)